# PTIJ: How do you prove G-d is The BOSS?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

How can you prove, directly from the Divine Name, that G-d is The BOSS?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya!

Comment: See also https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1081

Comment: @Rabbi Kaii Thank you for your welcome, and for fixing my post. I am sorry you deleted your own answer; did you think it was too irreverent, even for PTIJ? Chag Purim Sameach! L’Chaim!!

Comment: @msh210 I can’t deny my post is a clothesline for a geschmacky vort because I can only guess at what geschmacky means; Yiddishkeit is not my native schtick. (Hat es gut Geschmack? Google is not helping; if only there were a forum in which I could ask questions about Jewish matters). But seriously, isn’t this common in PTIJ posts? I admit my clothesline is balder than most, just a piece of string on which to hang a schmatter, but would it be better dolled up with a sheytl and lipstick? Chag Purim Sameach! L’Chaim!!

Answer (score 5):

Consider the Divine Name, the very Name, the Tetragrammaton. It is composed of four letters of the alefbet: the tenth letter, the fifth letter, the sixth letter, and the fifth letter. Now in the Latin alphabet (the modern Latin alphabet as used in English, Spanish etc.) the tenth letter is 'J', the fifth is 'E', the sixth is 'F', and the fifth is 'E'. Remembering that another of G-d's names is "El" we see that G-d is El JEFE, The BOSS.

Answer (score 0):

He's the boss but also Av Em and Ben as well as Boss, because YHWH is the entirety of everything.

Answer (score -1):

B"H

How do we know Hashem is the Boss?

Well the Hebrew word בת, Boss, is Gematria 402.

This is to be contrasted with the divine name בן, 52, meaning "son"

So if Hashem's name can be a son, and Hashem is also His own parents, and He keeps the commandments, and one commandment is pru urvu, which means to have at least one son and one daughter, then if He has the name בן it would stand to reason that He is also the בת, "Boss".